# Trying to get basic authentication work in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

I have a RESTful back-end server enabling the basic authentication. I would like to implement a GET request in my angularJS file to get some data from the server.

#### Code:

```
 angular.module('MyApp', [])
   .controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope, $http) {
         var userheader= btoa('username' + ':' + 'userpassword');
         
           $scope.getData=  function (){

            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://localhost:8000/data/',
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + userheader }
                };

     $http(req)
      .success(function(data) {
      $scope.mydata = data;
      }).error(function(){
           throw new Error('Somthing went wrong');
      });

 };
 });
```

When I invoked the function 'getData()',  it always give me the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resources".

Comment: can you remove $scope.mydata and try??

Comment: It still does not work.

Comment: Is the service you're trying to invoke running at that url?  (https://localhost:8000/data)?  That should represent a RESTful endpoint

Comment: Basic authentication is cumbersome, and exposes hard credentials for a long period of time.  I would suggest doing a username/password credential exchange and returning access tokens.  Here is a blog post that I recently wrote about this: https://stormpath.com/blog/why-we-rebuilt-with-angular/

Answer (score 0):

Your REST server needs to support [CORS requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in order to respond to client-generated requests.

Which framework is your server built with?

Comment: [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#_filter_requests_for_cors) should help ya out

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a bad idea (security wise) to use HTTP Basic authentication, even over TLS, in untrusted client applications (JS or mobile).  Any reason you're not using [Token Authentication for Single Page Applications](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/) ?